# Ajuda com "Prism Syntax Highlighter" não funciona direito

Tags: html, css

Estou com um probleminha ao adicionar "Pre Code" no meu blogger.

Quando eu adiciono códigos na marcação "language-css" por exemplo, os códigos adicionados funcionam perfeitamente, mas ao adicionar linguagens html na marcação "language-markup", ele buga, como mostrado na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e o certo é pra ficar desse jeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o código que eu uso para adicionar Linguagens HTML:

```html
<pre title="HTML" data-codetype ="HTMLku"><code class="language-markup"> ...Código HTML... </code></pre>
```

Onde está "...Código HTML..." eu substituo por quaisquer códigos HTML para a marcação do "Pre Code" como este por exemplo:

```
<div class="testprecode">Testando Código HTML</div>
```

Em vez de aparecer o código todo, aparece apenas "Testando Código HTML".

Isso só acontece quando eu adiciono na marcação "language-markup".

Quando eu adiciono css na marcação "language-css", fica bom, perfeito.

Agradeceria muito pra quem me ajudar, preciso muito disso no meu Blog.

Comment: Ah sim. eu fiz e deu certo, mas aí já pensei que eu ia perder muito tempo fazendo isso. Mas que bom que existe site pra copiar e colar. Obrigado e desculpa aí por fazer ou quase fazer você perder a paciência. kkkjj

Comment: Imagine, não foi isso não. Eu recomendei as melhorias pra ficar mais facil de alguém te ajudar, não era reclamação não. Sinto muito se deu essa impressão, mas não é isso. Sempre que usar o site, veja as recomendações das pessoas como uma maneira de facilitar a gente ajudar, é só isso.

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que está misturando o HTML que é para ser exibido com o HTML que monta a página.

A solução é fazer o *escape* do HTML interno desta forma:

```
<pre title="HTML" data-codetype ="HTMLku"><code class="language-markup">
    &lt;ul id=&quot;arlina-desing&quot;&gt;
      &lt;li class=&quot;active&quot;&gt;
        &lt;a href=&quot;#&quot;&gt;Top&lt;/a&gt;
      &lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;/ul&gt;
</code></pre>
```

Aqui tem uma ferramenta que faz esta conversão para você:

> http://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder

Lembre-se que além disso, a configuração de *white espace* do CSS principal tem que estar correta para preservar as quebras de linha e espaços de indentação.

Quando a pessoa usa uma linguagem *server side*, como PHP, tem funções prontas para isso, como `htmlentities( )` por exemplo.